# Why does npm init unable to successfully initiate in a directory?

Tags: node.js, npm

I was trying to run the `npm init` command, and I got this error:
I've tried several things, including trying it on another directory, and reinstalling node.js.
If anyone has any idea on what's going on, it would be greatly helpful. Thanks in advance.

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Windows\Documents\Programming\DiscordBot\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Windows\Documents\Programming\DiscordBot\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

Comment: You can try to check `npm` has already installed successful or not by `npm -v`. Also, you can try to install some package to check where the error is

Comment: When i did `npm -v`, I got `6.14.5`. When I tried installing a package, it just stopped midway.

Comment: Then, you can try to create new json file `package.json` in the directory `DiscordBot`. Inside the new json file, you write: `{ name: "xxx", version: "1.0.0", dependencies: {},  }`. Save it and try again

Comment: Now I'm getting the error saying it cannot write. `Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, write`

Comment: Maybe writing file in that directory requires a permission. You can try to create new project in the Desktop and try again

Comment: Wow, that really fixed it. I have no idea why an application wouldn't be able to edit a file in my documents folder, though.